# Проблема с фоном строк в Datagrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Имеется DataGridPeoples :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGridPeoples" CanUserDeleteRows="False" Margin="180,10,0,0" Height="718" Width="822" FontSize="15" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" CanUserAddRows="False" GridLinesVisibility="All">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Фамилия" Binding="{Binding Family, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CanUserResize="False"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Имя" Binding="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CanUserResize="False"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Отчество" Binding="{Binding Otch, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CanUserResize="False"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Номер" Binding="{Binding Number, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="auto" CanUserResize="False"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Дата рождения" Binding="{Binding BirthDay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged ,StringFormat=d}" Width="auto" CanUserResize="False"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Дата окончания" Binding="{Binding ExpirationDate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged ,StringFormat=d}" Width="auto" CanUserResize="False"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

На котором возникает событие:

```
DataGridPeoples.Loaded += DataGridPeoples_Loaded;
```

Или

```
DataGridPeoples.LayoutUpdated
```

Следующего содержания:

```
private void DataGridPeoples_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                foreach (People item in DataGridPeoples.ItemsSource)
                    {
                        var row = DataGridPeoples.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
                        if (row != null && item.ExpirationDate.AddMonths(-1) <= DateTime.Now)
                        {
                            row.Background = Brushes.Crimson;
                        }          
       }
}
```

Проблема заключается в следующем, при прокрутке формы цвет фона строк применяется к тем строкам к которым не должен применяться, насколько я понял проблема связана с виртуализацией, если сделать на Datagrid:

```
EnableRowVirtualization="False"
```

То все работает правильно, но работает очень медленно такой вариант меня не устраивает. Как можно реализовать окраску фона строк и виртуализацию в одном виде?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем проблема решена в англоязычной ветке по следующей ссылке:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133286/rowvirtualization-cause-incorrect-background-color-for-rows. по умолчанию в `Datagrid VirtualizationMode` установлен как `Recycling`.
Для решения этой проблемы рекомендуется установить `VirtualizationMode` в `Standard`

```
<DataGrid VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard" />
```

И изменить события для раскраски фона на `DataGrid.LoadingRow`

Надеюсь кому-нибудь поможет.

Answer (score 0):

У меня была аналогичная проблема, когда назначенный фон применялся к ячейкам, которым не должен, но это:

```
DataGrid.EnableRowVirtualization = false;
```

сработало для меня! Спасибо вам!

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо».  Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [проголосовать за вопросы и ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), которые сочтёте полезными. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/842351)

Comment: Возможно вы правы, но ведь я написал не просто «спасибо», а дополнил ответ фрагментом своего кода, это считается плохим тоном здесь?